# Python RotatingFileHandler is logging also to archived file - how to log multiple processes to single file

Tags: python, logging

This is my logging config:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,lan,publan

[handlers]
keys=nullHandler,consoleHandler,fileHandler,pubfileHandler

[formatters]
keys=full,simple

[logger_lan]
level=INFO  
handlers=fileHandler  
qualname=lan

[logger_publan]
level=INFO
handlers=pubfileHandler
qualname=publan

[logger_root]
level=ERROR
handlers=nullHandler

[handler_fileHandler]  
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
formatter=full
level=INFO
args=('/home/userx/lan/LAN_runtime_and_exception.log', 'a', 1000, 5)

[handler_pubfileHandler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
formatter=simple
level=INFO
args=('/home/userx/lan/LAN.log', 'a', 100000000, 1)

[handler_nullHandler]
class=NullHandler
level=DEBUG

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=full
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_full]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S
```

and I have about 10 different files which each of them has this exactly same logging setup:

```
import logging
import logging.config

#logging stuff
os.umask(0o002)
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger('lan')

#calling logger
logger.error("some error occured")
```

So far so good, now the problem. After restarting my application, all logging records are correctly sent to last file `LAN_runtime_and_exception.log`, but sometime later - few hours, few days, I dont know exactly trigger and time, I observe that also second last file `LAN_runtime_and_exception.log.1` is incrementing by some records from one of those 10 files that have logging set. I was not able to find why this is happening. My goal is to have all the time only latest file incrementing.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root    loggroup  17209 Dec 14 08:49 LAN_runtime_and_exception.log
this file is also incrementing >>>> -rw-rw-r--  1 userx loggroup   1035 Dec 13 14:42 LAN_runtime_and_exception.log.1
-rw-rw----  1 userx loggroup  99974 Dec 13 00:38 LAN_runtime_and_exception.log.2
-rw-rw-r--  1 root    loggroup   8550 Dec  6 07:48 LAN_runtime_and_exception.log.3
-rw-rw-r--  1 userx loggroup  99947 Dec  5 12:45 LAN_runtime_and_exception.log.4
-rw-rw-r--  1 root    loggroup   1246 Nov 28 21:37 LAN_runtime_and_exception.log.5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "and I have about 10 different files which each of them has this exactly same logging setup" – are those different processes, or different modules imported in the same process?

Comment: "I observe that also second last file LAN_runtime_and_exception.log.1 is incrementing by some records" is that file a *previously* existing one that none of the programs wrote to before, or is it a recently rotated one that the programs were already writing to?

Comment: @AKX Actually both variants, I have several files, that are imported by one main as modules and I also have file that runs as different process then main. Problem is that  after some time main process keeps logging into very last file and the second process is suddenly starting to log to 2nd last log file -> `LAN_runtime_and_exception.log.1`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this is previously existing file and I think problem starts to happen when last file reaches its rotation condition (size) then all processes instead of writing to last one, they split logging

Comment: Note that the rotation of ``RotatingFileHandler`` is not process-safe, and the writing happens by file identity (inode, file handle, ...) not file name. If multiple processes rotate files at the same time, the first to start rotating will have its new log file renamed by the other processes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks for clarification. So my only option is to use per process logger and per process log file name?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up imho at one very elegant solution and resolved the problem of logging multiple processes in single file using `syslogHandler` instead `ofRotatingFileHandler`, now logging on linux level using `rsyslog`. I did some testing and behaviour of syslogHandler is constantly fine.

Basic concept and code snippet here:

logging.conf (INI format)

```
[handler_syslogHandler]
class=handlers.SysLogHandler
formatter=full
level=INFO
args=(('localhost',handlers.SYSLOG_UDP_PORT),handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL7) <<- modify here as you wish
```

/etc/rsyslog.conf

```
#Custom Logging 
local7.* /var/log/mylog/mylog.log
```

/etc/logrotate.d/mylog

```
/var/log/mylog/*.log
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
    invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```